# How can I open a file in my WPF app, when the user double-clicks on that file?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I double-click on a file, I want my program to open and show the contents of that file. In Windows Forms, I can do this in my `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // I can read my content by using args
}
```

But in WPF there is no `Main` Method. How do I can do this?

Comment: Are you asking entry point for the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method in your main Windows Constructor it will give you the same values that are present in your args variable from your Main Method.

From above link:

> An array of string where each element contains a command-line argument. The first element is the executable file name, and the following zero or more elements contain the remaining command-line arguments.