# How can I make it so that files with a particular extension are opened using my .NET MAUI app when I double-click on them in the File Explorer

Tags: c#, file, xaml, maui

When I double-click a .txt file in the File Explorer, Notepad is launched and the file is automatically opened there. I want to be able to recreate this behavior with a .NET MAUI app - I want my app to launch whenever i double-click a file with a particular extension and I want my app to automatically open this file so that I can immediately start working with it as is the case with Notepad and .txt files.

I tried looking around in the .NET MAUI documentation and here on Stack Overflow, but the closest I could get is manually opening files with an already running app.

The question here mentions setting the app as default on Windows but this fact is stated as a given, while I don't know how I could go about doing this. Furthermore, if it really is necessary to set something in the system settings, I would like to make it so that my app's installer would take care of it. How can I do that? Here's the question I mentioned:
[How to use my app to open a file when I double-click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387363/how-to-use-my-app-to-open-a-file-when-i-double-click-it)

The question here says something about command line arguments, but it doesn't answer the question of how a file can be opened by double-clicking, and it also talks about frameworks other than .NET MAUI:
[How can I open a file in my WPF app, when the user double-clicks on that file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098517/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-my-wpf-app-when-the-user-double-clicks-on-that-file)

Comment: You can try to use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android) to open an app with a selected file. .NET MAUI automatically detects the file type (MIME), and opens the default app for that file type. For more information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android#open-another-app-via-a-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare the file type extension and the file type association in your .NET MAUI app's project manifest. Open the MauiProject.csproj file and add the following code inside the  element:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AppExtension Include=".YOURCUSTOMFILEEXTENSION">
    <ContentType>Text</ContentType>
    <RequestAccess>true</RequestAccess>
  </AppExtension>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then try to add a file activation event handler in your MauiProgram.cs file.

```
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(lifecycle =>
                {
                    lifecycle.AddWindows<FileActivatedHandler>((_, args) =>
                    {
                        // Handle the file activation event
                        if (args.Files?.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var file = args.Files[0];
                            var filePath = file.Path;
                            // Process the file as needed
                            // For example, open the file in your app's editor
                            OpenFile(filePath);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
                    // Register your app's handlers here
                })
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            return builder.Build();
        }

        private static void OpenFile(string filePath)
        {
            // Open the file in your app's editor
            // You can use the filePath to access the file contents and work with it
            // For example:
            // var content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            // Perform any necessary operations on the file content

            //await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
            //{
            //    File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath)
            //});
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't get it to work in MAUI 8. But [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321272/9102302) did work